# Is it possible to read a standard etherpad as a text document over the api?

Tags: etherpad

I have a public etherpad containing an yaml-file. Using php I would like read this yaml and convert it to a json-string.

There are some great libraries for converting yaml to json. for example: 
https://github.com/mustangostang/spyc/

What i'm looking for is an url that will return the contents of a pad as pure text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the text export then. You can easily get the contents of a pad exported as raw text, using the following url:

> `//<yourdomain>.com/p/<yourpad>/export/txt`

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it seems perfect to me

Comment: @BrianUnderwood probably because it doesn't play nice with iframes

Comment: `curl //<yourdomain>.com/p/<yourpad>/export/txt` works fine with only a text without any iframe

Comment: The problem is that this is serving the file as an attachment. Is there any way to get text content displayed as text/html?